# JSONPath check descendant value in predicate

Tags: javascript, jsonpath

In XPath, the following is possible:

**XML:**

```
<root>
    <parent>
        <child>
            <descendant status="passed">1</descendant>
            <descendant status="passed">2</descendant>
        </child>
    </parent>
    <parent>
        <child>
            <descendant status="passed">3</descendant>
            <descendant status="failed">4</descendant>
        </child>
    </parent>
</root>
```

**XPath:** `//parent[.//*[@status='failed']]`

**Result:** `/root/parent[2]`

(i.e. *get any parent node where any descendant has status "failed"*)

---

Using [Google's JSONPath implementation](http://code.google.com/p/jsonpath/), the following does not work:

**JSON:**

```
{
  parents: [{
      children: [{
          descendants: [{
              name: 1,
              status: "passed"
            }, {
              name: 2,
              status: "passed"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }, {
      children: [{
          descendants: [{
              name: 3,
              status: "passed"
            }, {
              name: 4,
              status: "failed"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**JSONPath:** `$.parent[?(@..status=='failed')]`

**Result:** `Uncaught SyntaxError: jsonPath: Unexpected token .: _v..status=='failed'`

In fact, any occurrence of `..` or `*` in the predicate causes a similar error. e.g.

1. `$.parent[?(@..status)]` causes `Unexpected token .: _v..status` and
2. `$.parent[?(@.*)]` causes `Unexpected token *: _v.*`

I also tried [dchester/jsonpath's implementation](https://github.com/dchester/jsonpath) and get the same problem, so I'm not sure whether or not this kind of behavior is supported by JSONPath. I'm not even sure who, if anyone, is defining the specification for JSONPath.

**Question:** Is this possible with JSONPath? (i.e. get an array of elements in `parents` who have any descendants with `status == "failed"` *without explicitly writing out the path*)

Comment: duplicate:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41878757/using-jsonpath-to-get-parent-node