# Using jsonpath to get parent node

Tags: jsonpath

Using node JSONPath, how can I get the parent node name from child node value

```js
{
  "store": {
    "book": [
      {
        "id":"1",
        "author": "Nigel Rees",
        "title": "Sayings of the Century",
        "price": 8.95
      },
      {
        "id":"2",
        "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
        "title": "Sword of Honour",
        "price": 12.99
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I use this expression to identify the child node based on value, I want to use this child node to find the parent node

```
$.[?(@.id =="1")]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28234347/how-to-find-parentnode-from-childnode-in-a-json-structure-using-jsonpath-or-an-a

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find parentNode from childNode in a JSON structure using jsonPath or an alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28234347/how-to-find-parentnode-from-childnode-in-a-json-structure-using-jsonpath-or-an-a)

Comment: You want to return the `store` in which you found the `book`?   Or you want to return the `book` that has that `id`?

Answer (score 9):

You do not specify which implementation of JSON Path, but with both Gatling (Scala) and JayWay (Java) you can use nested filters to filter by children while returning the parent, grandparent or whatever.  Here is a sample:

With this JSON:

```
{
  "a": {
    "b": {
        "c": {
            "d": {
                "e": "foo"
            }
        },
        "something": "bar"
    }
  }
}
```

And this path:

```
$.a.b[?(@.c[?(@.d[?(@.e == "foo")])])].something
```

Returns:

```
[ "bar" ]
```

I am able to retrieve `b` by using expressions to get to lower nodes as the filter.

Some other implementations error out on these expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, JSONpath does not support search by parameters in the contents of a child object:
http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/

Answer (score 1):

With JayWay it works but the query provided by Jayson is wrong, because if you change the value to "foo2" it will still return "bar".

This can be tested on http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/.

Query:

```
$.a.b[?(@.c.d.e=="foo")].something
```

Returns:

```
["bar"]
```

Query:

```
$.a.b[?(@.c.d.e=="foo2")].something
```

Returns:

```
[]
```